# Getting the data for each month

Tags: php, mysql

So what I want to do is basically this:

Month and Year:

-All the data sent on that month and year

For example:
February 2013:

-The posts on this date

March 2013:

-The posts on this date

and so on.

I have a date column on my table and it has the following format: day.month.year

I am using PHP and MySQL.

I have my own MVC framework that I'm using. I will simplify it to make it more understanble here. The function to fetch data:

```
function selectAll($sql){

    $find = $this->prepare($sql);     
    $find->execute();                      
    $fetchdata = $find->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);        
    return $fetchdata;
}
```

And the code to get the dates :

```
    $sql = "Select YEAR(Date) AS year, MONTH(Date) AS month, Headline from blog";
$data =  $this->db->selectAll($sql);
foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
        $date[] = $value['month'].'.'.$value['year'];

        }
$dateunique = array_unique($date);
```

This give me the results for the dates but I cannot figure out how to put the correct data under each date.

Comment: you only need to execute `SELECT * FROM tableName` and the formmating will be handled on `PHP`

Comment: Is the date column not a date?  Is it a `varchar`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_FORMAT` mysql function.

**Example**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%M') as Month,DATE_FORMAT(date_field,'%Y') as Year FROM table_name
```

and then debug result of `query` you will see two extra column for `month` and `year` then display it as your desire.

if `date_field` is `varchar` then use `str_to_date` mysql function.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_field,'%M') as Month, STR_TO_DATE(date_field,'%Y') as Year FROM table_name;
```

**OP question update**

Try `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT
*,
GROUP_CONCAT(created) AS month
FROM
table_name
GROUP BY MONTH(created) DESC;
```

Comment: okay I got this part already. when I have the year and months I put them in an array and by using the array_unique function I got rid of the duplicates. Now I am confused about how to get the data for each month

Comment: can you please update question so we can have better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the varchar date field into exact date using
   [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function
2. Using [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) you can select month wise record
3. Where `$input` is `%Y-%m` format // ex: 02-2013-> feb 2013

> ```
> SELECT * FROM `table` 
> WHERE DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(`date_column`, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m')= '".$input."';
> ```